# Google API Service Account

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to connect to the google doubeclick api through a service account (client email and p12 certificate), using the python client library as in the following example:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py

It's returning me an empty access_token:

```
In [9]: type(credentials.access_token)
Out[9]: <type 'NoneType'>
```

What is the significance of this? Is there something I am likely doing wrong? I have also tried accessing the tasks api as in the example (thinking that possibly the doubleclick api is not a supported scope) but same result.

**UPDATE (example code):**

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import httplib2
from adspygoogle.dfp import DfpClient

f = file('/path/to/.ssh/google-api.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('<email>', key, scope='https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher')
credentials.refresh(http)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

client = DfpClient.DfpClient(headers={'networkCode': '<code>', 'applicationName': 'test', 'userAgent': 'test', 'oauth2credentials': credentials})

inventory_service = client.GetInventoryService()
inventory_service.getAdUnitsByStatement({'query':''})
```

**ERROR:**

`DfpAuthenticationError: [AuthenticationError.NO_NETWORKS_TO_ACCESS @ ]`

Comment: Nope, no refresh token either (it's also blank)

Comment: Try passing `--dump_request_response` as an additional command line flag. This should dump the conversation with the server to stdout, so you can see what's going wrong.

If you're running in a [i]python session (as above), you want to do: `import gflags; gflags.FLAGS.dump_request_response = True`

Comment: I get a `KeyError: 'dump_request_response'`

Comment: Oops -- that's my mistake. *apiclient* uses that flag, not *oauth2client*. Can you inspect any of the other returned objects to see if something's hiding an error message?

Comment: Can't see any other errors, I've looked at all the attributes for credentials.

In [9]: credentials.invalid
Out[9]: False

Comment: I mean errors on the request you made to the server, which is (I'm guessing?) where the `credentials` object came from in the first place?

Comment: I managed to get an access token after `credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())`. However, when trying to use the API I get an authentication error. I suppose this means that service accounts are not yet a supported means of authentication for the doubleclick api?

Comment: Can you post a complete example (modulo any personal info)? 

It's totally plausible that doubleclick doesn't support service accounts.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? It seems that I can't access through service account either. The credentials.access_token is none.

Answer (score 0):

The NO_NETWORKS_TO_ACCESS error specifically means that you did authenticate to the API endpoint but that your account isn't associated with a network. Search for that error on this page https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201203/InventoryService?hl=en.

You either need to have the Google account you are authenticating as invited to the network via the DoubleClick User Interface or you need to use impersonation.

A more specific writeup on DFP API and service accounts was recently posted https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/service_accounts to the documentation. I suggest you look at the alternative section of that documentation to determine if you might prefer an OAuth 2.0 installed flow.